# Correlation analysis of parameters

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have  a data table detailing  various histological parameters among 3 groups of patients- DLE, SCLE and ACLE.

I would like to know how we could do an analysis on the strenghth of the association of a parameter with a particular group.

Answer (score 2):

If the parameters are continuous variables, you can do an analysis of variance for each one.  That will isolate any group differences in the means.  You can also measure effect size, *d*, as the difference between two groups' means divided by their pooled standard deviation.

If the parameters are categorical (including binary), you can do a Chi-Square test to see whether there is any disproportionality.  Depending on the way this test is structured, you could compute an effect size using a metric such as Cramer's V, lambda, or the contingency coefficient.